# xcode 4.0.2 won't rebuild older projects for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios4, xcode4

I have installed xcode 4.0.2.  I open my old project writtent for xcode 3.
I try to build and get several errors of type:
"Apple Mach-O Linker *Id) Error"
Lots of symbols such as _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSAutoReleasePool are not known.
It says that they are "Undefined symbols for i386"

Comment: What are you trying to do with them, did you want to update them for the new OS or...? If so you will probably need to change your target OS in the actual project details. But Linker errors are generally caused by missing frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue opening an old project with a newer version of XCode / newer operating system. I had a project written in 10.5 and Xcode 3 and when I tried to compile and run in 10.6 I had very similar errors.
Chances are that you did not update your target's Build Settings.
Go into XCode and click on your target 
(the blueprint image at the top that has your projects name) then make sure you change all the values to what your system now has under "Build Settings", make sure you change "Base SDK", "Compiler for C/C++/Objective C","iOS deployment target" and "Mac os x Deployment target" to what you are trying to build for / the latest your system has.
For most of these settings you can chose "Compiler Default" and that will put you in the clear.

Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks and that's probably the case.  My question - can I build for SDK 3.0 (my old project's SDK) while working with XCODE 4.0.2?

Comment: Yes you can set "ios deployment target" to any version you want.

Comment: It will not let you set "ios deployment target" to anything before 3.0, but 3.0 and on are fine.

Comment: I can build the project fine for IOS 4.3.  When I try to build for 3.0 I get all these linker errors I mentioned above. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, most likely you dont have the SDK installed for 3.0,

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean it and see if all your frameworks are all still there.